# Why would the blue-footed booby be treif?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, non-kosher-species

Why would the [blue-footed booby](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-footed_booby) be treif? I can't see anything that would make it *not* kosher, and the Torah does not mention it (obviously) in the list of forbidden birds in [Vayikra 11:13-19](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.13-19?lang=bi).

Comment: Who said it wasn't kosher? (I'm not saying that it is)

Comment: Perhaps they are a type of "seagull" or "pelican"?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22315/kashrus-status-of-turkeys ; https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76150/how-do-we-know-that-penguins-are-non-kosher ; https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82300/why-would-muscovy-duck-be-treif ; https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67041/are-songbirds-kosher

Comment: @kouty [*treif*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treif) is colloquially used to mean "not kosher," in a general sense.

Comment: @Isaac Moses yes but this is a form of slang. This is a street language, not written language (I mean in halacha's books)

Comment: @Isaac Mose shktse is also not שקץ as treiiiiif is not trefa. this is a bad usage of a halachic word

Comment: @kouty Like it or not, in Yiddish and in Judaeo-English, *treif* means "not kosher," and its the term with which Yehoshua Sauer expressed his curiosity, so it's likely to be the term some others who are interested in the same information would use to search, so it's valuable for us to keep here.

Comment: @isaa fwiw I disagree with the rollback

Comment: @Isaac Moses this kind of speaking is tref in matter of halacha

Answer (score 2):

First off, let me say that you have purposed an excellent question. See [this](http://dafaleph.com/home/2015/12/3/fowl-play-is-turkey-kosher) fine article. The quotation below is taken from it.

> The Torah, in [Parshas Shmini](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.13-19?lang=bi), when informing us of the kashrus status of animals, lists specific types of birds that are not kosher. Ultimately, through derivation of the various “l’mineihu” words found in that section, Chazal (Chullin 63b, Rambam, Ma’achalos Assuros 1:14) identify 24 classes of birds that are not kosher, each one with many species. Any bird that is not from one of these 24 classes is kosher (Rashi, Chullin 61a d”h oaf, Shulchan Aruch YD 82:1). The problem is, however, that we can no longer identify the non-kosher birds that are mentioned.

The simple answer is that we do not have a tradition that the blue-footed booby is kosher, so we abstain from eating it because there is a small chance that it might be one of the forbidden fowls.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58319/discussion-on-answer-by-ezra-why-would-the-blue-footed-booby-be-treif).